# Use effect doesn't see state

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, setinterval, use-state, clearinterval

i'm working on a continuous notification (every 3 seconds and max 1 min), until user accept pending orders.

This is my code.
usePrevious is custom hook that gives me previous value of state.

I don't mind why, when setTimeout executes clearInterval(), 'notification' is null.
This problem cause loop in sound.

```
[.....]
    const [notification, setNotification] = useState(null)

    const previousOrderCount = usePrevious(newOrderCount)
    const previousPendingReservationsLength = usePrevious(
        pendingReservationsLength
    )

    const isToneActive = useRef(false)

    // sound notify for new orders
    useEffect(() => {
        if (
            !isToneActive.current &&
            newOrderCount > previousOrderCount &&
            user?.profile?.role === "manager"
        ) {

            // this prevent multiple triggers of sound
            isToneActive.current = true

            setNotification(setInterval(() => playNotification(), 3000))
            setTimeout(() => {
                clearInterval(notification)
                isToneActive.current = false
            }, 60000)
        }
    }, [
        newOrderCount,
        playNotification,
        user,
        previousOrderCount,
        stopNotify,
        notification,
        setNotification,
    ])

[....]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use another React ref to hold a reference to the interval timer. The issue here is that React state updates are asynchronous, so the `setNotification` state update doesn't immediately update the `notification` state for the `setTimeout` callback that encloses the current `null` state value.

```
const notificationRef = React.useRef(null);

...

notificationRef.current = setInterval(() => playNotification(), 3000);
setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(notificationRef.current);
  notificationRef.current = null;
  isToneActive.current = false;
}, 60000);
```